# The specified procedure could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007F)

Tags: c#, c++, dll, dllimport

My C++ DLL (called from C# application) works fine with Debug version (main C# app in Debug ) but release version(main C# app in Release) gives ***The specified procedure could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007F)]
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'D:\TestBluRay.dll': The specified procedure could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007F)*** error. I've verified all project settings and those appear to be same for both debug and release. Any idea why this fails for release version only?

Comment: Do you mean (1) using the debug version of the C++ DLL fails while using the release version succeeds, or (2) using the debug version of the C# application fails while using the release version succeeds?

Comment: Is it at all possible that the release version is for some reason actually seeing an older version of the DLL? E.g., as a result of accidentally copying the DLL file only into the debug version's folder? (An easy kind of mistake to make...)

Comment: Agree with the above commenters.  Specifically, I'd check that the DLL you're referencing that is present in the bin/debug folder, is an EXACT copy of the one in the bin/release folder as well.  Most likely, it's not, or it's missing altogether.  

Also, please edit your question and show us the full error, as displayed.  ;)

Comment: Some times the project dependencies doesn't rebuild everything. I normally delete the bin folder which forces a rebuild. You can check the date stamp of the .exe file to see if it has been updated.An error starting with 0x8 means there is a invalid pointer.The dll need to be in the release and debug folder. Normally when you add a reference the compile will copy the dll from source location to debug/release folder automatically. If you perform a rebuild it clears all the files from debug/release including the dll. You should never manually put add files in bin folder so they don't get deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Validate that the .DLL is present, and fully up-to-date between both \bin\debug (which works), and \bin\release (which is failing).

Most likely, the .DLL needs either recompiling, or simply copying in if it's a 3rd-party library.

EDIT: Your error indicates that the file may be missing entirely (DllNotFoundException), or that you're referencing a path/directory, instead of a fully qualified path name.  "\Drivers\Blu_ray.." isn't a fully-qualified path name, where "C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\Blu_ray.." etc., **would** be a fully qualified path name.

My guess is that \bin\release\ doesn't have \drivers\blu_ray, whereas \bin\debug\ probably does have \drivers\blu_ray...